# FileNotFoundException Android

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, android-assets

I have this very silly exception coming up and disturbing my mind.

I have an xml file in the assets folder which says where to find the content updates for my application.

So i used xmlpullparser to parse my assets xml file and then get the link from there then i use a code snippet as:

```
PullLoadData pld = new PullLoadData("versioncheck.xml",SplashScreen.this);
                pld.checkUpdate();
                int fileSize = 0;
                InputStream is;
                AssetManager assetMgr = getAssets();
                PullLoadData pldContent;
                File file = new File(getString(R.string.database_path)+ "ext");
                progressBar.setMax(100);
                for (int i = 0; i < pld.result.size(); i++) {
                    int results = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < issue.length; j++) {
                        if (pld.result.get(i).get("issue").equals(issue[j])) {
                            results = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if (results == 0) {

                        Log.i(TAG, "ZIP Link "+ pld.result.get(i).get("link"));

                        is = assetMgr.open(pld.result.get(i).get("link"));}
```

// i get the correct url to the zip file and using this link from browser i can download the zip file......... but i get FileNotFoundException while debugging.

Any ideas where am i wrong?

Comment: I guess we need to use URL url = new URL("your link"); and then use the URLConnection urlconn = url.openConnection();

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

Uri path = Uri.fromFile(new File("assets/yourxmlfile.xml"));